# Cannot access REST Controller on localhost (404)

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, kotlin

I'm new in kotlin spring boot,write simple rest web service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class SpringKotlinWsApplication{
    @GetMapping("/getUser")
    fun getUser()= User("sample","sample")

}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringKotlinWsApplication>(*args)
}
```

now configure local tomcat server on my computer,and when run the project and try to access that with this url:

```
http://localhost:4040/getUser
```

get this error:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report Message Not found Description The origin server did
>   not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
>   willing to disclose that one exists.

how can i solve that problem?

[My TOMCAT configuration image here](https://screenshot.net/lg668cl)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `@RestController` annotation

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
open class SpringKotlinWsApplication{
    @GetMapping("/getUser")
    fun getUser() = User("sample","sample")
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for answer,add @RestController but so get previous 404 error

Comment: @Simi did you find anything useful in Tomcat server log file? Are you sure that Tomcat is really launched on port 4040 and not 8080 (which is default)?

Comment: please review my question,end line my tomcat configuration

Comment: @Simi tomcat configuration seems to be OK. What about server logs?

Comment: How can see tomcat server log?

Comment: When you launch Tomcat from inside IDEA there must be a tab at the lowest toolbar  of the window. Look for Run/Debug/RunDashboard, then look for Console tab

Comment: @Simi don't give download links, attach the log (not the whole but the last one with Error) to your Question instead

Comment: my log file text about 40 line